# Returns a js variable as a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I like to pass a JS variable 'latlng' to a php variable, but it does't work. In the span it's working fine. The php variable in the end of the code is returns '[object HTMLSpanElement]' and the corret is my current location

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    var centerChangedLast;
    var reverseGeocodedLast;
    var currentReverseGeocodeResponse;


    function initialize() {

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(latlng);
            }, function() {
                handleNoGeolocation(true);
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }

        setupEvents();
        centerChanged();
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
            var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
            var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
            content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
    }

    function setupEvents() {
        reverseGeocodedLast = new Date();
        centerChangedLast = new Date();

        setInterval(function() {
            if ((new Date()).getSeconds() - centerChangedLast.getSeconds() > 1) {
                if (reverseGeocodedLast.getTime() < centerChangedLast.getTime())
                    reverseGeocode();
            }
        }, 1000);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            document.getElementById("zoom_level").innerHTML = map.getZoom();
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', centerChanged);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('crosshair'), 'dblclick', function() {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
        });

    }

    function getCenterLatLngText() {
        return '(' + map.getCenter().lat() + ', ' + map.getCenter().lng() + ')';
    }

    function centerChanged() {
        centerChangedLast = new Date();
        var latlng = getCenterLatLngText();
        document.getElementById('latlng').innerHTML = latlng;
        document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = '';
        currentReverseGeocodeResponse = null;
    }

    function reverseGeocode() {
        reverseGeocodedLast = new Date();
        geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: map.getCenter()
        }, reverseGeocodeResult);
    }

    function reverseGeocodeResult(results, status) {
        currentReverseGeocodeResponse = results;
        if (status == 'OK') {
            if (results.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = 'None';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = 'Error';
        }
    }


    function geocode() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address,
            'partialmatch': true
        }, geocodeResult);
    }

    function geocodeResult(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK' && results.length > 0) {
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    }

    function addMarkerAtCenter() {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: map.getCenter(),
            map: map
        });

        var text = 'Lat/Lng: ' + getCenterLatLngText();
        if (currentReverseGeocodeResponse) {
            var addr = '';
            if (currentReverseGeocodeResponse.size == 0) {
                addr = 'None';
            } else {
                addr = currentReverseGeocodeResponse[0].formatted_address;
            }
            text = text + '<br>' + 'address: <br>' + addr;
        }

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: text
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
</script>


<body onLoad="initialize()">
    <h1 style="display:none;">APP Google Maps - Localizar Latitude / Longitude</h1>
    <div style="position: relative; width:980px; left:50%; margin-left:-490px; height:90px;">
        <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:20px;">
        </div>

        <div style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:30px;">
            Localizar Região:
            <input type="text" class="form_contato" id="address" style="width:300px; margin-right:15px;" />

            <input type="button" value="Procurar" onClick="geocode()" class="form_contato">
            <input type="button" value="Adicionar ponto no mapa" onClick="addMarkerAtCenter()" class="form_contato" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; width:980px; left:50%; margin-left:-490px; height:40px; line-height:40px; text-align:center;" class="Caecilia17">Para realizar a pesquisa digite no formulario acima o endereço desejado.</div>
    <div style="background:#ffffff;">
        <div id="map">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px"></div>

            <div id="crosshair"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; width:980px; left:50%; margin-left:-490px; height:90px; margin-top:20px; line-height:20px;" class="arial15cinza">
        Latitude / Longitude: <span id="latlng"></span>
        <br />Endereço: <span id="formatedAddress"></span>
        <br />Nivel do zoom: <span id="zoom_level"></span>
        <br />
<?php
//escrevendo a variável JS pelo PHP
$latlng = echo "<script>document.write(latlng);</script>"
?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: PHP is a language that runs on your server.  Its job is to *generate* a page containing HTML/JavaScript/CSS to send to your browser.  Once that page is sent to the browser, the PHP has completed running.  Then it's up to the browser to run the JavaScript and render the HTML.  If you want to "send" something to PHP, you need to make a new request to the server (be it via a `<form>` POST, AJAX, or some other way).

Comment: P.S. `echo` doesn't have a return value, so doing `$var = echo '';` does nothing for `$var` (and I think may even be a syntax error).  P.P.S. ***Don't*** use `document.write`, there are better ways to append text to the page (if the page has been fully loaded, it will erase the entire page before "writing").

Comment: Use ajax to send your variable to a php file if you intend to save the result in a database.

Comment: This is a **lot** of code. Could you edit your question to include only the parts which are relevant to your question please? Have a look at "[*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to pass the javascript variable to a PHP page by way of query string.
You could do something like:

```
var newVar = "somevalue";
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com?variable=" + newVar;
```

and then grab it in the php page you pass it to like this

```
$phpVariable = $_GET['variable'];
```

I hope this helps, also google server-side vs client-side coding to help get a better understanding of how they interact